# Is there any way to connect csv data with text file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Dy1NFyfh8iPdoLPLVdpu-r9RZyCZwzt/view?usp=sharing

where PMID is there so I need to append with this Citation number which is in the CSV file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VNbJnHuvrc3GNhELmLYXMk3mwML4P7N9/view?usp=sharing

Text data is

```
PMID- 20301691
STAT- Publisher
DA  - 20100320
DRDT- 20210311
CTDT- 20000204
PB  - University of Washington, Seattle
DP  - 1993
```

Now CSV data is

[image: CSV dataset with ID]

I need to append all this data with specific PMID

so desired output will be

```
    PMID- 20301691
    Citation - 1   "I want to append this data with matching PMID"
    STAT- Publisher
    DA  - 20100320
    DRDT- 20210311
    CTDT- 20000204
    PB  - University of Washington, Seattle
    DP  - 1993
```

How it will be working with multiple datasets where it is found PMID and append it.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything with the `text` variable, would you mind including the code where you attempt to access the .txt file?

Comment: using os path i am accessing the file i also add both files url in question where you can see that!

Comment: Both the `text` as also the `csv` variables do only get set, but never get read again. Why have those variables if they don't do anything?
If you read the files with `os.listdir`, where do you then distinguish between `.txt` and `.csv` files?

Comment: I'm removing the code then you can suggest me

Comment: Don't get me wrong, having your own code there was absolutely correct. Without having your own code, this is just a 'please do my work' question.
But the intention of your code was unclear and needed further clarification.
Please add your attempt, write what you expect to happen and what actually happens. Then we can help you effectively.
In other words, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).